# Ktor Client, install (Auth)

Tags: authentication, token, bearer-token, ktor, ktor-client

Friends, help! When connecting the install(Autn) Ktor Client plugin, all requests where the Bearer token is placed first return 401 errors and only then work out as necessary, what could be the reason?

```
`install(Auth) {
    bearer {
        loadTokens {
            bearerTokenStorage.last()
        }
        refreshTokens {
            val refreshToken: Token = client.submitForm(
                startUrl, parameters {
                    append("grant_type", "refresh_token")
                    append("client_id", "admin-cli")
                    append("refresh_token", oldTokens?.refreshToken ?: "Token not found")
                }
            ) { markAsRefreshTokenRequest() }.body()
            bearerTokenStorage.add(BearerTokens(refreshToken.accessToken, refreshToken.refreshToken))
            bearerTokenStorage.last()
        }
        sendWithoutRequest { request ->
            request.url.host.startsWith(baseUrl)
        }
    }
}`
```

It’s easier to write what i haven’t done yet, haven’t tried to write a custom plugin implementation yet, perhaps. At the moment I'm inclined to believe that this behavior of Ktor Client is the norm, but I'm not sure, help!

Comment: I've commented in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-6159